# what is the best way to prevent the program from breaking when receiving a user input in java?

Tags: java, validation, exception, input, java.util.scanner

I learned exceptions with try catch, but i dont know if this is the propper way to secure the program. For example, when i use a scan.nextint, and the user enters a string, what is the best way to prevent that? Try catch, or something else?

Comment: `Scanner#hasNextInt`

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to use try-catch. With this, you can catch any kind of error and react (execute a block of code) appropriately.

Comment: Actually, I would suggest that `Scanner#hasNextInt` is a better approach, as you should not be using `try-catch` as a flow control mechanism (where possible).  Although to be honest, I'd be tempted to just read the next token as a `String` and convert it manually, but that's me

Comment: try catch is not a good approach in simple scenarios. If you are not sure about type of input. then just take it as string by Scanner.next0 and then convert it or check type before converting and prompt again if it is not required